# C# WinForm UI design for multiple data entry

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I am working on Windows Form Application and came across to a situation where I need to insert, edit or remove the multiple records, like e.g, purchase order in which I need to add, edit and remove the purchase items as well as change the quantity.

Currently, I am adding the purchase items with quantity and rates to `DataGridView` from multiple `TextBoxes`, editing the items by retrieving it to `TextBoxes` again and deleting it by selecting the row/s.

This is very complicated and hard.

Is there any other simple way where I can do these 3 activities (add, edit, remove) at the same place and then save all items to database on single click.

Comment: You know you can add/edit/delete records from DataGridView, don't you?

Comment: The DataGridView from his name seems to be a control made to view things, when I must do this kind of operations, I use third parties grids. There are several producers of this kind of components, like Syncfusion, Telerik, Devexpress, Infragistics. their Grids got built in editing features to help you solve the problem. Some of them Have also some community program to obtain components free of charge. If you can't or Won't use third parties components, you must create a derived control from the datagridview and implement the editing part.

Comment: Yes I know... but I don't know how to add an event `OnTextChanged` for `ItemCode` to retrieve an `ItemName` and `ItemRate` and then calculate total amount by inserting the `Quantity`... any idea on this?

Comment: @Sabrina_cs really? So you can't add/edit/remove records using DataGridView only?

Comment: That's a totally different question Rajendra. I suggest opening a new question asking that and posting relevant parts of your code

Comment: Why don't you just use data binding? You should just add/remove items from the underlying collection. The grid and text boxes should just display the bound data. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3665/Data-binding-concepts-in-NET-windows-forms

Comment: @Pikoh Sorry, I'm a very lazy programmer so I prefer already made controls to avoid spending a lot of time doing what somebody better than me already did ;o)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to capture the 'RowsAdded' event of the datagridview and do whatever you need with the info.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So you mean if I add/edit the row at run-time then with the help of `RowsAdded` event I can able to do these things of retrieving data and calculation?

Comment: In that case you also have to use other events such as CellValueChanged